How to fix Laravel Validation error: 'The field is required'?
Why am I getting this error: The remarks field is required.? Note that the remarks has a value. When I dump the validated request, the remarks exists. The introduction field is same as the remarks but it works correctly. I don't know why it happens only to remarks.
remarks is also included in the $fillable array of the model. I also did form submission inspection using browser developer tools and check if remarks field is being sent in the request payload.
Store
class StorePurchaseRequestRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Gate::allows('purchase_request_create');
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'code' => ['string', 'nullable'],
            'cost_comparison_id' => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:cost_comparisons,id'],
            'introduction' => ['required', 'string'],
            'remarks' => ['required', 'string'],
        ];
    }
}

Controller
public function store(StorePurchaseRequestRequest $request)
{
    dd($request->validated());
    $purchaseRequest = PurchaseRequest::create($request->validated());
    $purchaseRequest->savePurchaseRequestSupplierItems($request);

    if ($media = $request->input('supporting_documents', [])) {
        Media::whereIn('id', data_get($media, '*.id'))
            ->where('model_id', 0)
            ->update(['model_id' => $purchaseRequest->id]);
    }

    $toRecipients = $this->getRecipients($request->to_recipients);
    $ccRecipients = $this->getRecipients($request->cc_recipients);
    $purchaseRequest->notify(null, $toRecipients, $ccRecipients);

    return (new PurchaseRequestResource($purchaseRequest))->response()->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}

Validated Request
array:7 [ // Modules\PurchaseRequests\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\PurchaseRequestApiController.php:75
  "code" => "PR"
  "introduction" => "<p>Test</p>"
  "remarks" => "<p>Test</p>"
  "cost_comparison_id" => "2"
  "correction_notes" => null
  "is_apm" => "0"
  "purchase_request_suppliers" => array:1 [
    // ... items
  ]
]

